# Python - programs works in Linux but not in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, pip

I am extending a program that run without any issue in my Linux machine but not in Windows. I need to make it in Windows because the Linux machine has some issues in maintaining the Bluetooth connection.

This the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProject.py", line 106, in <module>
    application = Server(options, args)
  File "myProject.py", line 42, in __init__
    super(Server, self).__init__(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\Server\lib\kernel.py", line 30, in __init__
    inject.configure(self.__configure_dependencies)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\inject.py", line 102, in configure
    _INJECTOR = Injector(config)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\inject.py", line 230, in __init__
    config(binder)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\Server\lib\kernel.py", line 58, in __configure_dependencies
    module = importlib.import_module(module_source, False)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'src\\myProject_config\\module'
```

I am sure the problem is with the environment not with the code that is why I did not include any.

Comment: on windows you probably don't have a folder called "src". Make sure in your code all of your file paths are changed.  might help to make a venv on linux and then activate that venv on your windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue awhile back on one of my projects when switching from mac to windows. Turns out I just had a more recent version of the language on my windows machine that didn't like the way I did some things, I would first check the versions of your IDE as well as Language, then if they arent matching compiling your program on the linux machine and transferring the compiled version to your windows machine. If it runs fine like that, try to get matching versions of the language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did not solve my issue but I just thought this would stop the flow of downvotes.